# Best way to store data that's constantly being accessed

Tags: c++, qt, store, updates

Until now I've been using structs to store data and then putting these structs inside a QHash.

```
struct Event {
    QString languageCode;
    QString message;
    //QMap<QString, QString> messages; Ignore it. Won't be using it.
    QString prop;
    qint64 dateSec;
    qint64 dateUsec;
    qint64 startDateSec;
    qint64 startDateUsec;
};

    QHash<QString, Event> eventList;

    Event event;

    event.languageCode = "en";
    event.message = "";
    event.prop = "www.google.com";
    event.dateSec = 1429554399;
    event.dateUsec = 0;
    event.startDateSec = 0;
    event.startDateUsec = 0;

    eventList.insert("ab1443c323956", event);

    // Test...
    qDebug() << eventList.value("ab1443c323956").prop;
```

Is this the best approach to store data that's constantly being accessed and sometimes being modified? This is small but there won't be only one key in the Hash.

Comment: This should be migrated to codereview.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#algorithmic-complexity) to see what the different container strength and weaknesses are?

Comment: If you use lookups by key and don't need `QMap`'s ordering by key, you should use `QHash` instead because it provides faster lookups by key.

Comment: How do you access your data? post some sample code, that gets something from `eventList`.

Comment: It depends on your actual access pattern, the number of items in the map and the length of the strings, but generally speaking, using QMap with QStrings as keys is about as inefficient as it gets.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek I edited the question with more testing code I've been using. I've been reading that QHash is better if you have more elements and since I don't need to sort by key, just lookup by key.

Comment: @Dimbreath: Please don't edit the question in a way that invalidates all comments/answers - your initial question was about QMap, now you are asking about QHash

Comment: @MikeMB Should I re-edit back to QMap and add a note about the QHash instead? Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From code you posted:

```
eventList.insert("ab1443c323956", event);

// Test...
qDebug() << eventList.value("ab1443c323956").prop;
```

I assume, that you either hard-code identifiers of events (which are of type QString now) or save them somewhere. In this case, I would use [QVector](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html):

```
extern int ab1443c323956_index;

QVector<Event> eventList;

Event event;
//fill data

eventList.push_back(event);
ab1443c323956_index = eventList.size() - 1;

// Test...
qDebug() << eventList[ab1443c323956_index].prop;
```

Now, since you always append events (`QVector::push_back()` is equivalent to `QVector::append()`), you have following complexities:

- insertion: constant amortized ( Amort. `O(1)` )
- index lookup: constant ( `O(1)` )

For data, that is constantly accessed - nothing can beat this in terms of speed.

Of course, this solution is valid, if you can use integers as your "keys", but when it comes to operations like this one, even `QHash` can introduce significant overhead.

Comment: The identifiers that I use as a key come from a json file and they identify _(like a unique id)_ the event.